# Split Definition List into multiple columns when <dd> present or not

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to split a list like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Title of Column 1</dt>
    <dd>data for col 1</dd>
    <dd>data for col 1</dd>
    <dt>Title of Column 2</dt>
    <dd>data for col 2</dd>
    <dt>Title of Column 3</dt>
    <dt>Title of Column 4</dt>
</dl>
```

into multiple columns. Sometimes there will be dd elements, sometimes no. I was thinking I could probably use nth child but then I'd have to know how many items there will be, and I won't. Is there any other way to accomplish this without breaking it into multiple definition lists?

Thanks.

Comment: Any screenshot to say you want this?

Answer (score 0):

If browser support allows for it, you can use CSS Columns and the `break-before` style applied to the `dt` tag.

Given your HTML, the following CSS will give you the desired result:

```
dl {
  column-count: 4;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 300px;
}

dt {
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
  break-before: column;
}
```

Note: You need to ensure that the height of the column is at least as tall as the header and data for each column.

Browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before
(IE 10+, Opera supported. Chrome and Safari with a browser prefix. Firefox unsupported).